# Weird behavior of conda when creating empty environments

Tags: anaconda, conda

I create a conda environment without specifying any packages using the following command:

```
conda create --name test_env
```

I can then use all the packages in the root environment inside test_env (but they do not appear in the outputs of conda list and conda env export). This is already unexpected to me but the real problems begin when I then install something inside that environment, e.g.:

```
conda install pywavelets
```

Afterwards, pywavelets is usable but all the other packages which are no dependencies of pywavelets disappear inside the environment (e.g. pandas). I don't understand why that happens. Does anybody have an explanation for that?

More importantly, what does this mean for best practices for working with conda environments? Should I always create my environments specifying at least python (conda create --name test_env python)? However, then I have to install everything by hand in that environment which is quite cumbersome. So, my idea now is to specify anaconda for all environments I create:

```
conda create --name test_env anaconda
```

The disadvantage, however, is that the list of dependencies listed by conda list and conda env export gets unnecessarily long (e.g. even listing the Anaconda Navigator). Does anybody have a better solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you can use all the packages from the root environment when you don't specify a Python version during environment creation is because you're actually using the root environment's Python executable! You can check with `which python` or `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`. See also my [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45863425/2449192).

When you install `pywavelets`, one of the dependencies is (probably) Python, so a new Python executable is installed into your environment. Therefore, when you run Python, it only picks up the packages that are installed in the `test_env`.

If you want all of the packages from another environment, you can create a file that lists all the packages and then use that file to create a new environment, as detailed in the Conda docs: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#building-identical-conda-environments
To summarize

```
conda list --explicit > spec-file.txt
conda create --name myenv --file spec-file.txt
```

or to install into an existing environment

```
conda install --name myenv --file spec-file.txt
```

Since that's just a text file, you can edit and remove any packages that you don't want.

Comment: I know that I can create an identical environment with the commands you explained above, that's not what I want to do here. I was just very surprised by the behavior when creating an environment without specifying anything. That's clear now, so thanks for the explanation!

Comment: The reason I mentioned the identical environments is because you asked if you had to specify all the packages you wanted by hand. The answer is yes, unless you use a file that contains the appropriate definitions.