# Conda - all packages available to use even though new env is 'clean'

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have an issue with package management with conda when in comes to available packages. For example:

1. I made a clean Anaconda install
2. I'm created a new env:

   `conda create --name new_env`

This is successful.

3. I start it:

   `source activate new_env`

This is successful.

4. I list the available packages:

   `conda list`

This returns no package installed as expected and desired.

Problem: Even though env is 'clean' all packages are available to use (either I run spyder or from generic python console - for example Flask)

Question: How do I isolate available components when creating new env so only components explicitly installed in it are available?(returned by `conda list`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of non-separated anaconda environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329107/what-is-the-use-of-non-separated-anaconda-environments)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find the answer myself.

When no package is installed in clean environment generic version of Python/Spyder is run - exported in PATH(I just did not notice):

```
/home/zigmunt/anaconda3/bin/spyder
/home/zigmunt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Only after installing the package explicitly in the environment PATH is updated and 'local' version is run having access only to content installed locally:

```
/home/zigmunt/anaconda3/env/new_env/bin/python
/home/zigmunt/anaconda3/env/new_env/bin/spyder
```