# Do newly created conda envs inherit all packages from the base env?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda and created a new env ("dell_proj"). Then I created a new Project in Pycharm with my new environment. My expectation was that I would only be able to use packages in this project that I installed through Conda in that specific env, however, I am able to use all packages that were installed in the Base environment.

[Packages shown available in Conda for env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7mj7.png)

[Packages shown available in Pycharm for env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyNgH.png)

Could somebody explain what I'm misunderstanding here?

Comment: Please also do not post terminal/code output in images. Please see here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45863425/2449192

Comment: How did you create the environment? Please include the code you used...

Answer (score 21):

You can create a clone of the base environment using
`conda create --name dell_proj --clone base`. This will create a new environment that is a copy of your base environment.

If you created the new environment using something like `conda create --name dell_proj`, it will not inherit packages from the base environment. You would have to install the packages you want using `conda install`.

Answer (score 9):

In windows you create an environment without specifying the python version, then it will create the new environment with all packages in base. I don't know if it is a bug or a feature but this works in windows.

```
conda create -n new_env
```

creates an environment with base packages

```
conda create -n new_env python=3.7
```

creates new environment only with some necessary packages given below

```
ca-certificates    
certifi            
openssl            
pip                
python             
setuptools         
sqlite             
vc                 
vs2015_runtime     
wheel              
wincertstore
```

Comment: This no longer appears to be true on WIndows 10; creating a `new_env` as specified creates an environment with nothing in it. Running e.g. `spyder` from within the new environment is not recognized :(

Answer (score 0):

I am using Anaconda x64-4.4.0 with Python 3. I created a new Python 2 environment, and it only imported a few basic packages. So it would seem the answer depends on how the environment was created.