# Conda Environment on Intellji IDEA

Tags: python, machine-learning, intellij-idea, anaconda, conda

I installed Intellji IDEA and I saw that I could create a Conda Environment. 
I'de like to know if with Conda Environment I can use in Intellji the Python packages that I already have in Anaconda, and what's the procedure to accomplish that.
Thank You

Comment: One way to do that it described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52433854/10895914

Then to use the cloned environment in IDEA, select "existing environment" and point to python interpreter from that environment.

Comment: Thank you, but is It  not possibile to use the base(root) ?

Comment: AFAIK, should be completely identical to PyCharm, so this a duplicate of [Use Conda environment in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746732/use-conda-environment-in-pycharm). And, yes, you can point it to the the **base** env if you wish. I would be cautious though, since you really want to keep **base** env as stable as possible. It is preferable to create a new env for each project.